# Kaplan-Meier survival graph explanation

Tags: survival, kaplan-meier

I have used [gepia2](http://gepia2.cancer-pku.cn/) site to look for survival associated with genes I output something like this

I understand this part which is Logrank p value which shows PTDSS2 gene high and low group have survival differences but what is HR(high) and p(HR)? how do i interpret that

[image: gene survival]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this software fit a [Cox proportional hazards model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_hazards_model) to the data. In survival analysis, the [hazard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Failure_rate#hazard_function) at a given time $t$ is the ratio of the probability of an event (death here) to the probability of having already survived that long without an event.

The `HR` is then the *hazard ratio*, the ratio of hazards between the two groups. Under the proportional hazards assumption, that ratio is constant across time and is a simple summary of the association of group membership with outcome. In this case, a member of the "high" group has 4.8 times the hazard of that of a member of the "low" group.

The *p*-value is an estimate of the probability that so large a hazard ratio might be found by chance if there were no real difference between the groups. There are 3 ways to calculate a *p*-value for a Cox model. I suspect that the one reported here is based on a Wald test of the regression coefficient (the log of the `HR` value), but you would have to read the manual or ask the software developers to be sure.

That said, be very very cautious when interpreting this type of survival analysis based on gene-expression data. In the extreme, if you evaluated all ~20,000 genes individually for associations with survival in the way that this software seems to operate, you would find 1000 "significant" genes at the usual *p* < 0.05 (1/20) criterion even if none were truly associated with survival. At the least you have to make corrections for [multiple comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem).

There's also a big risk that the expression of a gene is just a stand-in for some already established clinical risk factor. It's important to evaluate how much *additional* information the gene-expression levels provide *beyond* what's available from clinical characteristics.

If you are going to pursue survival analysis, read up on it and work out some test cases for yourself. The main [survival vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/survival.pdf) and the R [`survival` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=survival) provide a good way to start. There are almost 3000 questions [tagged `survival`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/survival) on this Cross Validated site.